# Android Sqlite: Is there a way to control the number of duplicates cols you get within a single query?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have a table of books when each book contains tag and a name. Now I want to get 10 different books for each tag. I thought about using distinct or group by, but this removes all the duplicates. Does anyone know of a method to control the number of duplicates?

```
ID   NAME   TAG
-----------------------
1    GREEN  adventures
2    RED    adventures
3    YELLOW love
4    BLACK  adventures
5    WHITE  love
6    PURPLE Fantasy
```

Results for 2 copies of the same tag:

```
ID   NAME   TAG
-----------------------
1    GREEN  adventures
3    YELLOW love
4    BLACK  adventures
5    WHITE  love
6    PURPLE Fantasy
```

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

With `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
select b.id, b.name, b.tag
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by tag order by random()) rn
  from books
) b
where b.rn <= 10
```

This will return 10 random books for each tag.
If you want the 10 first books by `id` then change:

```
order by random()
```

to:

```
order by id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/27rDUfEgCmL22QLhMs77Xx/0).
Or for older versions of SQLite which do not support window functions:

```
select b.id, b.name, b.tag
from (
  select b.*, (select count(*) from books where tag = b.tag and id <= b.id) rn
  from books b
) b
where b.rn <= 10
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/27rDUfEgCmL22QLhMs77Xx/1).

Comment: I tried that just now and it gives me an error , could it be because Im on android?

Comment: Android uses an older version of SQLite which does not support window functions like ROW_NUMBER(). I will post another solution, less efficient of course, for older versions.

Comment: well it works but this solution is too inefficient it takes for it around 1s for 2k raws and my table length is around 60k.Thx anyway

Comment: I mentioned that. It can't be compared to window functions.